# jQuery .hasClass, .closest() and $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to highlight the parent `tr` of a table, if a children `td > p` has a certain class. I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $target = $('.flag-wrapper p').closest("tr");
    var $element = $('.flag-wrapper p').hasClass("selector-on");

    if ( $element ) {
        $target.addClass("marked-row");
    } else {
        // whatsoever
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cZJca/1/

Now my problem is that I can't target just the current **tr**. I've tried using $(this) but as far as I can tell it won't work inside the if statement.

Any insights on how should I proceed with this would be much appreciated. Also, I guess it would be easier to work with a .click() event but I have to check this .hasClass() on page load instead of user action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use:

```
 $('.flag-wrapper p.selector-on').closest('tr').addClass("marked-row");
```

This finds all `p` elements inside `.flag-wrapper` that have the class `.selector-on`. It then gets the closest `tr` of each of the matches and adds the `.marked-row` class.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/cZJca/6/

Comment: :) I think I should get some rest, I tend to over complicate things. Thank you for your answer, it's work perfectly of course. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `closest`? If the cells are in nested tables, `parents` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over each one and deal with it separately.

```
$('.flag-wrapper p').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $target = $this.closest("tr");

    if($this.hasClass("selector-on")){
        $target.addClass("marked-row");
    } else {
        // whatsoever
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do

```
$('tr:has(.flag-wrapper p.selector-on)').addClass('marked-row');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gJ8Uc/)

or

```
$('tr').has('.flag-wrapper p.selector-on').addClass('marked-row');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pzdxq/)

Comment: You don't know whether the `.flag-wrapper` is a descendant of the `tr`

Comment: Huh? why wouldn't it be? it looks like it in the fiddle

Comment: @Bergi also in the OP `I'm trying to highlight the parent tr of a table, if a children td > p has a certain class`

Answer (score 0):

You can [loop](http://api.jquery.com/each/) over the paragraphs to target them individually:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flag-wrapper p').each(function() {
        var $curElement = $(this);
        if ($curElement).hasClass("selector-on")) {
            $curElement.closest("tr").addClass("marked-row");
        } else {
           // whatsoever
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.flag-wrapper p.selector-on').closest('tr').addClass('marked-row');
```

Comment: Can you please extend your answer and explain a little bit what is done wth this line?

Comment: You can already read it in the best answer to this question :)

Comment: So where is the use of your answer then? It does not contribute anything useful to the original question.

Comment: I answered the original question, but there ahead of me